# How to join divs or div content without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, media-queries, screen-resolution

I have this block in HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.taquaritinga.sp.gov.br/" target="_blank">
  <img src="img/logo_prefeitura.png" alt="Foto do brasão da prefeitura de Taquaritinga" class="img-responsive">
</a>
<div class="categoria_menu_wrap_down"></div>
</aside>
<aside>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="img/logo_troy.png" alt="Foto do logo da Troy Informática" onclick="return false" class="img-responsive">
  </a>
  <div class="categoria_menu_wrap_down"></div>
</aside>
</div>
```

My objective is to join these two `div`s in only one at a certain range of media screen, but I don't know how I can do that without creating two different pages for each resolution (what's necessary for this situation).

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49466190/edit) to include more information.

Comment: You don't need to create another page. You can add a third `div` with the merged content and at some resolution show it and hide the other two, while at other resolution hide it and show the other two. There are other ways two, but this is simple enough
.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a third `div` with the merged content and at some resolution show it and hide the other two, while at other resolution hide it and show the other two:

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .categoria_menu_wrap_down {
    display: none;
  }
  .categoria_menu_wrapped {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .categoria_menu_wrap_down {
    display: block;
  }
  .categoria_menu_wrapped {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="categoria_menu_wrap_down">- First div</div>
<div class="categoria_menu_wrap_down">- Second div</div>
<div class="categoria_menu_wrapped">* First div<br />* Second div</div>
```

Note: The media queries in this example are only for demo. You need to adjust them to suit your needs. I've also used dashes in the separate `div`s and asterisks in the merged `div` for demo so you can see it changing when resizing your browser. In your case, the content should probably be identical.